# Checking generic parameter at compile time

Tags: c#, generics

Say I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public MyClass() {
        //construct logic
    }

    public IProperty<T> MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public interface IProperty<T> { }

public DateTimeProperty : IProperty<DateTime>
{

}
```

If I try to put this code into the constructor of `MyClass`:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime))
    MyProperty = new DateTimeProperty();
```

I get the following compilation error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'DateTimeProperty' to 'IProperty'

How can I, in the constructor of MyClass, set the value of `MyProperty` to be a `new DateTimeProperty`, only if T is of type `DateTime`?

Comment: Have you tried converting it explicitly?

Comment: Using that construct is not really how generics is meant to be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that generics should really be exactly that; *generic*; what you are doing is *specialized* (for some `T`), which is kinda not the point. However, as for *how* - cast:

```
MyProperty = (IProperty<T>)(object)new DateTimeProperty();
```

By casting to `object` and then back up to `(IProperty<T>)` you remove the compiler's ability to apply static type-checking rules. And the downside: *you remove the compiler's ability to apply static type-checking rules*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marc. I am using the generic parameter throughout this class really. Closer to the truth is that I have a collection of `IProperty`, most of which are generic but some of which are type specific. Is there a design pattern you could recommend that is a better way of achieving this? Factory class for each type, perhaps?

Comment: @ConnellWatkins hmmm... factory sounds like over-complication it; try to keep it simple until you *need* the complexity. Whatever works...

Comment: Yup, I considered factories but thought exactly that. Sometimes you've just gotta know when putting a couple of not-so-recommended lines of code in would be more productive. Could I make a static method that accepts a `MyClass<DateTime>` object and sets `MyProperty` to the `new DateTimeProperty()`? The static type-checking rules would still apply here, wouldn't they?

Comment: @Connell meh, maybe just use the cast ;p Otherwise you'll just end up chasing it in a loop (moving the problem elsewhere, but not really changing it)

Answer (score 1):

While this is only a stylistic difference, I prefer the following over Marc's suggestion:

```
((MyClass<DateTime>)this).MyProperty = new DateTimeProperty();
```

Comment: That is neater, I like this one. I could even use the `as` keyword to avoid type checking then casting: `MyClass<DateTime> dt = this as MyClass<DateTime>; if(dt != null) { dt.MyProperty = new DateTimeProperty(); }`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not do that because then the generic is not generic anymore as Marc said, if you have a base class which implements all you need and you want to limit the `MyClass` to only be created with types deriving from your base class you can use the [where (generic type constraint) (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx):

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : YourBaseClass
```

Comment: My interpretation is that he doesn't what *all* `T` to be restricted to `DateTime`, but rather: when the `T` ***is*** `DateTime`, apply some specialization.